# Finding all complex $z$ that satisfy $z^4+4z+8=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, factoring, quartics

I was given this task:
 $$z^4+4z+8=0$$

And I am totally stuck at solving this. The university handed out some solutions that are the following:$$z=−2±2i$$

And well... plugging this into the function obviously works but I have no idea on how to get to that solution.

What I tried was to seperate the term into two halfs that look like this:
 $$z^4+4z+8=(z+a)^2\cdot(z+b)^2 = 0$$
Then I could have solved $$(z+a)^2 = 0$$ $$(z+b)^2 = 0 $$

But I did not find an a and b that work in this case. Therefor I am asking how this would usually be solved.

Greetings, Finn

Comment: those aren't the roots to that quartic.  the quartic doesn't appear to have roots of a pleasing form.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I guess it is a quadratic equation.

Comment: No its not. I copied everything correctly

Comment: you can set $$z=a+bi$$ then you will get an equation system in$a,b$

Comment: @Peter  Really?  The OP appears to try to factor it as a product of two quadratics.  I agree that the given roots apply to the quadratic.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h9fwat (screenshot of the task)

Comment: @lulu So whoever who made the task probably did not write it down correctly?

Comment: By Wolfram alpha the roots of the quartic are $z ≈ -1.21367 \pm 0.805637 i,z ≈ 1.21367 \pm 1.51557 i$.  As I say, not pleasing.  So, yes...I expect the person who set the problem intended to write $z^2$.

Comment: If this is actually the equation, we do not have "nice" solutions.

Comment: Oh wow... Gonna blame my tutor then. Thank you :)

Comment: The numbers $-2 \pm 2i$ are roots of the equation $z^2+4z+8=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the maximum, which you can make here it's the following.
$$z^4+4z+8=(z^2+k)^2-2kz^2-k^2+4z+8=(z^2+k)^2-(2kz^2-4z+k^2-8).$$
Now, choose a value of $k$ such that
$$2^2-2k(k^2-8)=0$$ or
$$k^3-8k-2=0.$$
One of real roots of the last equation will get the difference of squares

and you'll get two quadratic equations and all roots, but it's very ugly of course.